# print page is different from Chrome and IE

Tags: html, css, oracle, printing, oracle-apex

I have a table (interactive report from APEX ORACLE) to print so I call a function which calls window.print()

Testing the page on different browsers I see that in Chrome the page is printed correctly: the tables fits inside the page, instead in IE the row is truncated, goes out of 'page'

How can I get the same result as chrome?

I've tried using if condition checking if it's IE and set css but nothing

Comment: Which version of IE are you using ?

Comment: Hello, I'm using IE 8

Answer (score 0):

IE8 is a very old browser and it is not supported by most web applications. Do you have to support IE8 ? If possible then try using a newer version of IE such as IE 11 and see if the issue occurs there. For IE8, you can try adding `table-layout: fixed;` to your table CSS.

Comment: I'm gonna try it and tell you, ty

Comment: In IE 11 and even with table-layout: fixed set in CSS ?

Comment: I need to fix it for IE 8..that's what the client is using